# SDK in pubspec.yaml not same as in flutter --version

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to set environment sdk version to a higher number but it says that my current SDK is as seen below:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.4.

Because demo_app_1 requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because demo_app_1 requires SDK version >=2.16.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

When i run `flutter --version` i get the following:

```
Flutter 3.1.0-0.0.pre.854 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ec20ea80ad (17 hours ago) • 2022-05-21 16:28:06 -0400
Engine • revision 1bfe551d6b
Tools • Dart 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-142.0.dev) • DevTools 2.13.1
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See you're confusing two things.

The dart SDK version that's mentioned in `pubspec.yaml` is for the `'dart'`
version to be used in the project, not the `flutter` version.

Important to note that every **dart version** is compatible with a corresponding **flutter version**. The dependency can be loose though.

So in your case `Flutter 3.1.0-0.0.pre.854` is the flutter version and `2.18.0` is the dart version. This shows that your `flutter 3.1` is compatible with `dart 2.18` and is installed, but your project uses `2.14.4`

You can check the available list from [flutter SDK releases](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `demo_app_1` requires an SDK version >= (higher or equal) 2.16.0 but < (below) 3.0.0. The version you have installed is 3.1.0, which does not fulfill the requirement.

You have two options:

1. Change your flutter installation version

   - `flutter downgrade <version>`
   - `flutter doctor`
2. Change the required SDK version in your `pubspec.yaml`

   - Change the `environment->sdk` value
   - `flutter pub get`

After that, the issue should be resolved.

Comment: Isn't the SDK version for the Dart SDK? Because when I modify the environment SDK version to `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0" ` it runs fine.
As the current SDK is 2.14.4, when I modify the SDK range above 2.14.4 I get the error above.

Comment: I have flutter version 3.3.10 on my Macos, however, when I create a project it is set up with environment sdk lower than 3... then as a matter of fact I cannot run projects with '>=3.0.0-68.0.dev <4.0.0' dependency.. Any help? What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter downgrade 3.0.0` and check if solved

Comment: I have a prompt for version 2.10.5 and not 3.0.0. Do I need to install it manually?

Comment: If that doesn't work, download SDK from https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases and paste in current SDK folder. Or else for Windows, open the Edit environment variables for your account GUI window, select User variables and edit the Path entry by appending the full path to the Flutter SDK bin. The Path variable uses ; as the value separator. If the Path entry doesn't exist, just create a new entry named Path.

Comment: Does the SDK version in the pubspec file need to match with when I run `flutter --version` ?
Because when I run flutter pub get, its showing that the current dart SDK version is 2.14.4.
When I run `flutter --version` the dart SDK version is 2.16.2.

Comment: Could you change SDK version of pubspec file to 2.16.2  manually?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out. I believe that this is causing the errors. Is there any way I can change the SDK version that the pubspec file is getting?

Comment: Are you using any package that uses previous/outdated version of flutter? If so try to get the lates one